# How to make values descend by recent?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a basic commenting program that Displays a persons name and their comments. So I was wondering how *would I make the comments display by recently commented* instead of by the first, second, third, fourth, fifth.

**index.php**

```
<?php //index.php

    require_once 'login.php';
    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to server: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server) or die("Unable to select database:       ");

    if (isset($_POST['post_name']) && isset($_POST['post_message'])) {
    # code...
    $post_name = get_post('post_name');
    $post_message = get_post('post_message');

    $query = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES" . "('','$post_name', '$post_message')";
    if(!mysql_query($query, $db_server)){
        echo "INSERT FAILED: $query <br />";
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
    }
    }

    echo <<<_END
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <pre>
    Name    <input type="text" name="post_name" required/>
    Message <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="post_message" required>Enter ur                message here lol</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

    </pre>
    </form>
    _END;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result) die("database acess failed:" . mysql_error());
    $rows= mysql_num_rows($result);
     for ($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++) { 
    # code...
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo <<<_END
    <pre>
    Name: $row[1]
    Message: $row[2]

    </pre>

    _END;
    }

    function get_post($var){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
    }

    ?>
```

Sql file for this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
post_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
post_message varchar(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
)
```

Comment: you have posted date in "Post" table ?

Comment: You will need to modify your query `SELECT * FROM posts` to use an `ORDER BY` on some column.  That being said, please give us all the columns from the `posts` table.

Comment: Stop using mysql_* libraries, please. They are deprecated! use PDO instead.

Comment: what is pdo? and can u link me to it?

Answer (score 0):

Add "ORDER BY post_id DESC" to the query string.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC";
```